# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()

Tags: laravel-5, request

I am using session in Laravel 5.1 and here is my Controller code :

```
Route::post('/task', function (Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

   
});
```

I need to use session, and getting this error :
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure you're importing the right Request class at the top of the file:

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

At the moment it looks like you're using the Request facade

Answer (score 3):

There is also possible ways to use

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

instead of

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

at the top. hide "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;"

Hope it works. Thank you.